# Performance issue with gulp.watch() on directory with ~400 files

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-watch

I’ve noticed that if I `gulp.watch()` a directory with ~400 Markdown files, my Gulp task takes a long time to initialize (~19s on my machine). If I remove this specific `.watch()` call, my task initialization time shrinks to less than 100ms.

```
gulp.task('my-task', function () {

    // these calls are very quick (< 100ms) 
    gulp.watch('source/styl/*.styl', ['build-css']);
    gulp.watch('source/js/index/*.js', ['build-js']);
    gulp.watch(['app.js', 'modules/*.js', 'routes/*.js', 'views/*.jade'], [server.run]);
    gulp.watch(['source/js/index/*.js', 'app.js', 'modules/*.js', 'routes/*.js', 'gulpfile.js'], ['lint-js']);
    gulp.watch('source/img/**/*', ['compress-images']);

    // this call takes ~19s to complete
    gulp.watch('source/md/releases/*.md', ['build-releases']);
});
```

Is there anything I can to to resolve this performance issue, or is watching directories with hundreds of files not feasible in Gulp?

---

**Update:** I have switched to a callback function:

```
gulp.watch('source/md/releases/*.md', function (e) {
    // console.log(e.path);
});
```

and I’m still experiencing the same performance issue.

Comment: What does `build-releases` do exactly? It might not be just gulp, but the things that happen when that task executes.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer It’s actually an empty function: `gulp.task('build-release', function () {});`. I haven’t written it yet.

Comment: Oh, must be gulp then.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer I’ve created an issue https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/845. I hope there is a fix for this ^_^